# best way to get folder and file list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, filesystems

I'm using node-webkit, and am trying to have a user select a folder, and I'll return the directory structure of that folder and recursively get its children.

I've got this working fairly simply with this code (in an Angular Controller).

```
var fs = require('fs');

$scope.explorer=[];
$scope.openFile = function(){
    $scope.explorer = [tree_entry($scope.path)];    
    get_folder($scope.path, $scope.explorer[0].children);
};

function get_folder(path, tree){
    fs.readdir(path, function(err,files){
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        files.forEach( function (file,idx){
            tree.push(tree_entry(file));
            fs.lstat(path+'/'+file,function(err,stats){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                if(stats.isDirectory()){
                    get_folder(path+'/'+file,tree[idx].children);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    console.log($scope.explorer);

    return;
}

function tree_entry(entry){
    return { label : entry, children: []}
}
```

Taking a moderate sized folder with 22 child folders and about 4 levels deep, it is taking a few minutes to get the entire directory structure.

Is there something that I'm obviously doing wrong here? I can't believe it takes that long, seeing as I'm using the built in Node fs methods. Or is there a way to get the entire contents of a directory without touching each and every file?

I'm going to want to be able to use an Angular filter on the file names all the way down the tree, and possibly on the contents too, so delaying processing the entire tree isn't likely a solution that would work.

Comment: Perhaps it is getting .. as a file. You probably should put a few console.log's around to learn a little more about what is happening.

Comment: You mean it is opening each file? No, that doesn't seem to be the problem, I was about to delete the question, turns out if I removed the console.log and put in a callback which output to the console once, things happen much faster.

Comment: What i meant was .., the parent directory, but that was a longshot. Good you found the solution though

Comment: What you need is a simple recursive walking function that traverses a directory. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In my project I use this function for getting huge amount of files.  It's pretty fast (put `require("fs")` out to make it even faster):

```
var _getAllFilesFromFolder = function(dir) {

    var filesystem = require("fs");
    var results = [];

    filesystem.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {

        file = dir+'/'+file;
        var stat = filesystem.statSync(file);

        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
            results = results.concat(_getAllFilesFromFolder(file))
        } else results.push(file);

    });

    return results;

};
```

usage is clear:

```
_getAllFilesFromFolder(__dirname + "folder");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this non-recursively?

Comment: 'require' function is not defined.

Comment: @Jacob it has reasons why there is node.js in the tags

Comment: Its giving error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: @GeekyInt you probably have a symlink in your directory structure pointing to a containing folder. In that case you can use `fs.lstat()` instead of `fs.stat()`.

Comment: For an efficient, non-blocking (async) technique using Node's fast `fs.Dirent` objects, I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62197577/633183) to this thread.

Answer (score 3):

**fs/promises and fs.Dirent**

Here's an efficient, non-blocking `ls` program using Node's fast [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects and [fs/promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) module. This approach allows you to skip wasteful `fs.exist` or `fs.stat` calls on every path -

```
// main.js
import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

async function* ls (path = ".")
{ yield path
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield* ls(join(path, dirent.name))
    else
      yield join(path, dirent.name)
}

async function* empty () {}

async function toArray (iter = empty())
{ let r = []
  for await (const x of iter)
    r.push(x)
  return r
}

toArray(ls(".")).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Let's get some sample files so we can see `ls` working -

```sh
$ yarn add immutable     # (just some example package)
$ node main.js
```

```
[
  '.',
  'main.js',
  'node_modules',
  'node_modules/.yarn-integrity',
  'node_modules/immutable',
  'node_modules/immutable/LICENSE',
  'node_modules/immutable/README.md',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/README.md',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/__tests__',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/__tests__/Cursor.ts.skip',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/index.d.ts',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/index.js',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable-nonambient.d.ts',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.es.js',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.min.js',
  'node_modules/immutable/package.json',
  'package.json',
  'yarn.lock'
]
```

For added explanation and other ways to leverage async generators, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032850/633183).

Answer (score 0):

Why to invent the wheel?

There is a very popular NPM package, that let you do things like that easy.

```
var recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

recursive("some/path", function (err, files) {
  // `files` is an array of file paths
  console.log(files);
});
```

### Lear more:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir

Comment: This solution doesn't list the directories itself

Comment: seems a bit much to install an entrie package fro something so simple

Answer (score 0):

I don't like adding new package into my project just to handle this simple task.

And also, I try my best to avoid RECURSIVE algorithm.... since, for most cases it is slower compared to non Recursive one.

So I made a function to get all the folder content (and its sub folder).... NON-Recursively

```
var getDirectoryContent = function(dirPath) {
    /* 
        get list of files and directories from given dirPath and all it's sub directories
        NON RECURSIVE ALGORITHM
        By. Dreamsavior
    */
    var RESULT = {'files':[], 'dirs':[]};

    var fs = fs||require('fs');
    if (Boolean(dirPath) == false) {
        return RESULT;
    }
    if (fs.existsSync(dirPath) == false) {
        console.warn("Path does not exist : ", dirPath);
        return RESULT;
    }

    var directoryList = []
    var DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR = "\\";
    if (dirPath[dirPath.length -1] !== DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) dirPath = dirPath+DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    directoryList.push(dirPath); // initial

    while (directoryList.length > 0) {
        var thisDir  = directoryList.shift(); 
        if (Boolean(fs.existsSync(thisDir) && fs.lstatSync(thisDir).isDirectory()) == false) continue;

        var thisDirContent = fs.readdirSync(thisDir);
        while (thisDirContent.length > 0) { 
            var thisFile  = thisDirContent.shift(); 
            var objPath = thisDir+thisFile

            if (fs.existsSync(objPath) == false) continue;
            if (fs.lstatSync(objPath).isDirectory()) { // is a directory
                let thisDirPath = objPath+DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
                directoryList.push(thisDirPath);
                RESULT['dirs'].push(thisDirPath);

            } else  { // is a file
                RESULT['files'].push(objPath); 

            } 
        } 

    }
    return RESULT;
}
```

the only drawback of this function is that this is Synchronous function... You have been warned ;)