# How to add js script with unknown filename?

Tags: javascript, json, file

When you normally wish to add a js script from a subfolder, you use: `<script src=foldername/filename.js></script>`

I have a specific local folder that's called `jsfiles` and it's placed within the same folder level as the main script calling it. But there are an unspecified number of js files with unknown names, each having one JSON files as arrays defined in it.

All files look like: `var json = [{...},{...}]`

How do I set up a for loop to push EACH json object in EVERY file in the `jsfiles` into an array, although I don't know the names to the files?

Or do I need another programming language than JavaScript for that matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, you can't do that, you have to generate the list of file names or include the files beforehand on the server side.

Comment: Well, you have to fetch a list from the server first.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I generate the list of filenames?

Comment: can you describe what technologies you are using on your server (ASP.NET, Ruby/Rails, PHP, etc.) so we can more accurately point you in the right direction?  this is a server side process, not a client side process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get all the files in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822273/best-way-to-get-folder-and-file-list-in-javascript)

Then:

```
jsArray.forEach(function(j) {
  $('head').append('<script src="...." type="..."');
});
```

Comment: It's better to include the code from mentioned question in your answer. In case that question will deleted and your link become irrelevant.