# Page that displays topology of the directory

Tags: html, file, directory, topology

Is there any way to do this:

```
  <h1>Topology</h1>
<ul><li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="File1.mp4"> File1.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File2.mp4"> File2.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File3.mp4"> File3.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File4.mp4"> File4.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File5.mp4"> File5.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File6.mp4"> File6.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File7.mp4"> File7.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File8.mp4"> File8.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File9.mp4"> File9.mp4</a></li>
<li><a href="File10.mp4"> File10.mp4</a></li>

</ul>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wagyox71/

Is there any way to do this without listing every single file separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript.

Create a div for the list, then use a script and an array to populate the div.

The div: `<div id="myLinks"></div>`

```
    var links = ['<a href="/"> Parent Directory</a>', '<a href =""> File1.mp4</a>', 'File2.mp4', 'etc'];
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementById('myLinks').appendChild(ul);

    links.forEach(function(name){
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML += name;
    });
```

You can manually populate the `links` array, or do it dynamically from a directory on the site via some other call.

Comment: Is there any way to make the array contain all the files in the same directory instead of writing them one by one? I want to display about 300 files

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript) answer seems to have what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you will try