# Create javascript variables from adirectory files list

Tags: javascript, variables, directory-structure

I have a code with a list of variables like this:

```
var sounds = {
  "hello" : {
    url : "sound/hello.mp3"
  },
  "gasp" : {
    url : "sound/gasp.mp3",
  },
  "scream" : {
    url : "scream.mp3",
  }
};
```

the directory "sound" contains a lot more so for the sake of convenience I would like javascript to automatically list the files and create the variables accordingly. I read somewhere javascript cant access client side directories so if thats the case what alternatives do I have to achieve this?

P.S. I CANT use PHP, my server doesnt support it and I cant change that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

Comment: if you're using javascript on the server side you can list the file using fs , but if you're working with javascript on the client side you cant

Comment: No, its not a duplicate because mine is more complex...

Comment: What can I do then?

Comment: @Cain Nuke Take a look at this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158134/generate-a-nested-structure-based-on-a-list-of-file-paths/158135#158135

Comment: But is that possible on client side javascript?

Comment: Help please?????