# Getting a file list from a directory on client side

Tags: javascript, variables, directory-structure

Hi,

I have a list of variables in javascript I want to automatically populate with the file list of a given directory. This is the file list:

```
hello.mp3
gasp.mp3
scream.mp3
...
```

and the variables would look like this:

```
var sounds = {
  "hello" : {
    url : "sound/hello.mp3"
  },
  "gasp" : {
    url : "sound/gasp.mp3",
  },
  "scream" : {
    url : "sound/scream.mp3",
  }
};
```

the problem is that I CANT use PHP because my server doesnt support it and I cant change that. This on the client side so I guess that doing it with javascript is also out of the question. What alternatives do I have to achieve this?

Comment: JavaScript can not read directories on the clientside.

Comment: You cannot access the file system from the client side. Is there anything else you can use server-side?

Comment: That's not possible. You'll have to run a script server-side. That could be PHP, or any other server language.

Comment: Yeah there is no way, even if the folder is in your server.

Comment: The only way to get the file list, is to make the user click a button. And select the files.

Comment: What about externally? A php page on another server that creates the list and then get it from there?

Comment: Other servers do not have access to other server's filesystems. What is your server and what does it support? php is not the only server side language

Comment: Its a chat server. It supports java, javascript and html as far as I know.

Comment: For all those claiming no way to read directories, I challenge you to expand your thinking and reviewing my answer below. Although this does not overcome the OP's constraints, I hope you find it instructive.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** This doesn't get beyond the OP's constrained environment (nothing does actually). But I'm leaving this here because it seems a lot of people don't realize this can be done (with Chrome).

In spite of the comments, you actually **CAN** read a directory on the client side with the right browser. But, it **requires user action**.

Not perfect, but does address your constraints.

In order to get the directly list, the user must open a file open dialog and choose the directory. At that point you can iterate the list of files on the client and automatically populate your data structure as you wish.

You must use Chrome and the input must be set up like this:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory="" directory="">
```

Sample here (remember, this only works in **Chrome**):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRdbYq

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need it to do it automatically and on all major browsers.

Comment: With those constraints there is no client side solution unless you move to a platform specific app. Perhaps built with ElectronJS.

Comment: When I go to the directory on my browser like this example.org/sounds/ I can see the list of files. Cant I have javascript read those?

Comment: The requirement stated in your question is to get the list of files. But, yes, you will be able to read all files in that folder

Comment: I mean, to have javascript get the list from there.

Comment: Yes, here is an updated pen. Choose a directory and look at the console: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRdbYq?editors=1111

Comment: @RandyCasburn op is wanting to get a server's directory listing not a directory from the users own computer hence their asking about getting a listing at url _"example.org/sounds/"_

Comment: @PatrickEvans - and I quote: _This on the client side_ from the OPs question. How do you get to the server side conclusion?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - You mean the second comment above. Yeah, I think the OP has not been clear on this.

Comment: i think they were just trying to convey that they were wanting to read/list/use the directory in a client browser, also they had _"the problem is that I CANT use PHP because my server doesnt support it "_ showing that they needed something server side unless they are completely unaware and think that servers can read a clients directory

Comment: Yeah - thanks. I think this one is kind of dead anyway. The constraints cannot be overcome it appears.