# how to make a button for every file in a repositry

Tags: html, button

I am trying to make a program that will make a button for every file in a directory.

[They need to go equally on both the red lines on **this** image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj44N.png)

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Games</title>
    <style>
        html, body {

            background-color: #000000;
        }
        .text {
            background-color: #000000;
            font-size: 100%;
            color: #00ff00;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        a {text-decoration: none;}

        .button {
          padding: 15px 25px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 770px;
          left: 45%;
          font-size: 50px;
          cursor: pointer;
          outline: none;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 15px;

        }

        .button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

        .button:active {
          background-color: #3e8e41;

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <h1 class="text" style="font-size:300%;">Thing</h1>

        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="600" height="600">

    </div>

</body>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to use some php

Comment: how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

reddit.com/r/domyhomework

In all seriousness though, you need to provide more information. What sort of language are you working with besides HTML and CSS?

Obviously, your first step will be generating a list of the files in your directory. I don't know if these files are server side or client side, but here is a good place to start:

[Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)