# How to generate HTML href code with directory files

Tags: javascript, html, loops, href

I need to generate a static HTML href code which is in loop, except the source of the image. The images are stored in one folder. Is there a way with javascript how to generate the whole directory and to put the filenames into the `src="/pictures/%filename%.jpg"`? There are a lot of pictures and I don't want to link every single photo by hand. It would cost a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the links stores in an array?

Comment: Javascript is clientside (normally). Because of security reasons you cannot do this directly using javascript. You need server side logic to retrieve the file locations as a list. Then you can send this list to the client to do with it whatever you want.

Comment: are you using any server-side markup generated tools, like ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: technically it is possible if directory listing is enabled, but that is a really bad idea, as the comments above say, use server side scripting (node, PHP, ASP, etc) to generate the html

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad explanation. I don't want for the clientside to finish this loop. I want to produce a local app to generate the src="/pathtopicutres" with the directory pictures and to paste it the pictures.html file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

Comment: This post only list the files. I need a loop with an static html source code which only the source of the images is changing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I've uploaded this php file on the server:

```
<?php
$dir    = 'best-off';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files1 as $file){
    echo "
    <div>
      <span class='img-thumbnail d-block cur-pointer'>
        <img alt='' src='img/best-off/thumbs/" . $file . "' class='img-fluid'>
      </span>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

then I looked into the source code in the browser and copied the code into the initially HTML file. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can't access server files. You can use PHP [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get an array of all files within the specified directory. Then do

```
foreach ($arr as $file){
    echo "<img src='/path/to/file/" . $file . "'>";
}
```

Comment: Thats a useful answer. Can I put my whole HTML code in there and put the . $file . into the img src=""? Will this code produce the html source code for all files in the directory?