# How can I get a list of files in a directory?

Tags: javascript, html, list, directory, names

I'm trying to make a simple webpage that you can input a directory path in and it lists all the files in that directory. Is there a way I can do that directly in the .html file with js script? I have the path as a variable.

I'm very new to these programmin languages and don't know much about these.

Answer (score 0):

A webpage does not have access to a client's file system. No website can see your files.

However, if you're talking about server side javascript, that's different. Server side javascript file listing can be achieved through this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/assets/photos/');
```

Reference: [Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

Hope that helps

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: `FS` - File saver, is only defined when it's not running as a web page. If you have an express server it will work but if you're just making an html website then it won't work. A web page cannot read a user's files

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1 (upload files with html):**

You need to be more specific. But i will supose that you want to navigate into files for upload some file on your webpage:

You could do this and when you press the button you will can navigate in your files and select as you want:

```
<input type="file" name="" id="">
```

**EDIT 2 (using server languages for working with files):**

**First step:** you need a lenguage server as php or nodejs (it use internally javascript chromev8). I recomend you to use nodejs becose its easier for people who already know javascript.

If you wanna nodejs, install it:
https://nodejs.org/en/ .
If you wanna php you can install apache xampp that also install a version of mysql database:https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

**Second step:** working with files:
php https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dio.php
nodejs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system (you will need to know about synchronous and asynchronous programming).

Comment: I want to browse files in the server.

Comment: Ok, you can do that, but not with html or javascript in the client side (front-end). You need to use a server languages as php or javascript with nodejs (back-end).

Comment: Guess I need to dig in deeper into those. I have no idea how they work. I'm more of a python guy :D

Comment: Yes, also you can use python. To know how server lenguages work may take time, but dont worry, then it become easy.