# How do you make into array of URL paths out of image folder files? Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, directory

How do I make an array of all the file URL paths without doing each one manually, using JS?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWsT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the [readdirSync()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdirsync-method/) function.

```
Returns: It returns an array of String
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)