# How to retrieve the file names from local directory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file

So what I want to do is to retrieve all the file names from a local directory using JavaScript and then populate these filenames in html form with separate checkboxes for each filename, Kindly help.
A sample code for this task would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

From browser No, client side Javascript has no access to filesystem

Comment: This used to be true, but it is now possible to access the local filesystem from client-side JavaScript using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Comment: So when using FILE System API user must select a folder and give access to read the files?
@AndersonGreen

Comment: Yes, the API allows client-side JavaScript to read or modify directories that are selected by the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using ajax. Send an ajax request to a php file, there retrieve filenames using php and send it as ajax response. You'll get it.

JS code

```
$.ajax({
    url : URL_TO_PHP_FILE,
    type : "get",
    success:function(res){
       console.log(res)
    }
});
```

PHP code

```
$dir = "/images/";
$a = scandir($dir);
/*
Sample output of $a
Array
(
  [0] => .
  [1] => ..
  [2] => cat.gif
  [3] => dog.gif
)
*/
echo json_encode($a);
exit;
```

Comment: If its not much of an issue, Can you share a sample code for this task which might help because I was searching for the solution in JavaScript because of not much familiarity with these two.