# NodeJS - no such file or directory, scandir '/static/reports/'

Tags: node.js

I tried following this stackoverflow post to try and see my folder on my static webpage but no luck:https://stackoverflow.com/a/31274417

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('./persistence');
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./static/reports');


app.use(require('body-parser').json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));



db.init().then(() => {
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

const gracefulShutdown = () => {
    db.teardown()
        .catch(() => {})
        .then(() => process.exit());
};

process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGUSR2', gracefulShutdown); // Sent by nodemon
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like from vscode:
[image]

Here is a picture of the error from docker:
[image]

Here is the error from text:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:269

    throw err;

    ^


Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './static/reports'

    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:955:3)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.js:5:16)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

  errno: -2,

  syscall: 'scandir',

  code: 'ENOENT',

  path: './static/reports'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a file path with a `/` denotes that it's at the root of the filesystem. Don't use a `/`; instead, just use `static/reports`. You can also use `./static/reports` if the code will be run from the `src/` directory every time.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('static/reports/');
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense because of the `/` is root in linux so that makes logical sense. HOWEVER, that didn't work for me. I think that is my fault as I didn't put all the code into the post, I just put in the picture. I added the full code. I think it has something to do with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));` but I can't tell. I apologize as this is my first time using node.js and I am using the getting started image from docker to learn docker. I updated my post to put in the full code.

Comment: @SOUser418 Shouldn't `var files = fs.readdirSync('reports/');` be `var files = fs.readdirSync('static/reports/');`?

Comment: I also tried the following:
`static/reports/`
`./static/reports`
`static/reports`
`reports/`
`./reports/`

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect that, and post the error (as text)?

Comment: I updated the post to reflect `./static/reports` and gave the text error. Thanks

Comment: Try using `__dirname + "/static/reports"`. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but it's worth a try. If that doesn't work, can you tell me the output of `console.log(__dirname)`?

Comment: That was the ticket! I am still not sure how to access `/static/reports` from the web browser BUT the docker build didn't crash! Very smart to use the `__dirname +` for the pathing. I am going to research the rest of the information from here. I gave you the upvote for the answer. Thanks again so much!!!