# Get files and folders with Static HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way I can use static HTML (and/or JavaScript) in the browser to get all the files and folders of the current project?
For example, I have the following structure:

```
./project
├── files-and-folders
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── 3.png
│   └── inner-folder
│       ├── 4.png
│       └── 5.png
├── index.html
└── index.js
```

I would like to open `index.html` in a browser, i.e. [file:///path/to/project/index.html](https://file:///path/to/project/index.html) and get the list of all files and folders under the `files-and-folders` folder.

I know you can use `fs` with NodeJS and read files and folders, but I was wondering if this can be achieved using static HTML or JavaScript.

The ideea is, that I would like to get all the files and folders from the `files-and-folders` folder, and display them inside my `index.html` file as a list.

Thank you.

Comment: Since `files-and-folders` does not have index page, you can just fetch content of `http://example.com/files-and-folders`, parse it and get links as content, rinse and repeat (that's like security issue here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

Comment: Not really. I needed an HTML file that I open in the browser like `file:///path/to/project/index.html`, and inside that file to load the list of files and folders under `files-and-folders` folder.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** *This should not be possible*

**Reasons:**

1. It it a security feature of JavaScript that it is not allowed to access client-side files (despite uploads via `input` elements), thus you cannot use a pure JavaScript solution to achieve what you want.
2. *If* you were looking for a server-side solution, pure JavaScript also wouldn't be an option as JavaScript is always executed on the client (no regarding NodeJS etc.) and therefore doesn't know anything about the server-side files.

**Your options:**

There might not be any easy way to achieve your goal. If you just want to show the `index.html` (or whatever) locally, which is how I understood your question, you could think about using the (non-JavaScript-;)) scripting language of your preference like Perl or Python. Your script could then look like this:

1. Dynamically generate your `index.html` as needed.
2. Open your browser shower this file.

Then you would have to make sure that your script is called to show the HTML file and the file is not opened directly as it might be outdated otherwise.

**Update: Why does using an URL like `file://path/to/project` in your browser work then?**

The browser is an application running on your local PC. Thus, it has the possibilities and permissions to access your local file system. This is done using the means the browser's programming language (like e. g. Rust) offers in conjunction with your operating system and hence not limited to what JavaScript offers.

You could open the `file`-URL you posted your browser and look at the source code of the page displayed. You'll find that the directory content names are inserted by some "magic" you don't see. In Firefox, you'll see lines like `addRow("Documents and Settings" ...` for example, if you open just
`file:///C:/` (on Windows). The `Documents and Settings` is originating from your browser querying your operating system for the contents of `C:\` and creating an `addRow` entry for everything found. This is a little similar to what I wrote in "Your options".

Comment: But how come the browser is able to list all the files and folders if I go to `file:///path/to/project/`?
Sorry, it may be dumb, but I am curious.

Comment: You're not dumb, it's a good question. :) Please see the update in my answer for the solution.