# Get a list of all files within a directory in a client machine using browser

Tags: native-file-system-api-js

The use case here is not that important though but the use actually is. I want to browse the users local file system via browser like we do via `<input type="file">` but instead of picking up a file I want to pick up a directory and get list of all the files and directories inside it.

Once I get that list of files I want to recursively show them in a treeview like structure.

This is a example of what I know can be done via [File System Access Api](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/text-editor/).

I just want to use this API to create something like a File Manager or a treeview.

Thanks.

Comment: Bye bye _privacy_, if you want to open the _entire_ disk drive like a file manager.

Comment: @JoopEggen It's not a attack on privacy. As the user will be picking the directory they want to give access by themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enumerate all files in a directory, call `showDirectoryPicker()`. The user selects a directory in a picker, after which a `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` is returned, which lets you enumerate and access the directory's files.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    console.log(entry.kind, entry.name);
  }
});
```

If you additionally need to access each file via `getFile()` to, for example, obtain the individual file sizes, do not use `await` on each result sequentially, but rather process all files in parallel, for example, via `Promise.all()`.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
  const promises = [];
  for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
    if (entry.kind !== 'file') {
      break;
    }
    promises.push(entry.getFile().then((file) => `${file.name} (${file.size})`));
  }
  console.log(await Promise.all(promises));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but why "not use await on each result sequentially"?

Comment: Processing sequentially would be slower. Processing everything in parallel is the faster alternative.

Comment: does your `for await` isn't sequentially wait for each of `dirHandle.values`?

Comment: The `FileSystemDirectoryHandle.values()` method returns an asynchronous iterator, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle/values#return_value). Getting a file via `getFile()` is the asynchronous operation that is being parallelized.