# Search through files in path using only javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, file

I'm coding a webpage that needs to read some data from different csv on a path depending on the country of the user.

the path is something like this:

```
./csv/m2-2022-10-25_13_45_55_es.csv
      m2-2022-10-25_13_45_56_fr.csv
      m2-2022-10-25_13_46_04_it.csv
      etc
```

And those files will be replaced regularly, the only that we'll always have is the country code (es, fr, it, etc).

So, what I need is to list all the files on the path to an array, and loop through the array to find if the last characters of the filename are $countryCode + ".csv", and there run some code.

But I can't find how, all the solutions I find are using Node.js, but are there a solution using only Javascript (or jQuery)?

Regards!

Comment: You'll need a way for the server to reply with the files in the folder. A user in the front-end is not allowed to browse through the server files if there's not an endpoint to do that, as that's usually a security problem. Depending on the backend you have, you have to develop a backend code. You can also maintain an array and fill it regulary with all the files that you are adding to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use pure Javascript to do that, because if you wanted to search files in your computer only using javascript, it would be a huge security breach.
You must use node.js to open files but you can make an API to your nodejs file from your javascript and you can send as a response the content of your file.

Here some links that might help you :

FS : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

NodeJS api : https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-simple-restful-api-in-node-js-ae4bfddea158

Comment: Thx for the fast response.
The files are not in my computer, are on the server

Comment: Oh so like that it's different, you only need to make a fetch.

Comment: Here the documentation of fetch : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can check a similar question here:

[Get list of filenames in folder with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript)

You can't access to filesystem from the frontend, this it would be a huge security breach, because anyone could access to your filesystem tree.
You have to do a function in backend to build the array you want and send it to frontend.

If you create a function in backend file that returns the array of files in the folder, you can call it from the frontend via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the array in frontend and be able to use in your js file.