# Get file names of in-app directory Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, file, directory, backend

I have a script ready that takes the url of audio files (that I have stored in the app-- they're right next to my js folder!) and parses them for their id3 tags.

Right now, I have to register each track url manually in my script. Is there a way that I could use angular to get all file names in a given directory so that I (or a client) could just drop new audio files into the directory without having to defer to some backend solution?

Comment: Sorry, javascript isn't able to read any server side folders

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn, he didn't say he is going to read from server side folders.

Comment: This was probably answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822273/best-way-to-get-folder-and-file-list-in-javascript

Comment: What framework are you using on the backend? Angularjs has nothing to do with reading files as you are trying to achieve.