# Recursively search through sub directories for specified directory name in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have a directory structure like this:

```
/git
    /content
        /repo1
        /repo2
        /repo3
    /modules
        /repo4
        /repo5
    /tools
        /project
            /repo6
            /repo7
        /test
            /repo8
            /repo9
```

I'd like to be able to find the path to a particular repo just by passing the repo name:

```
searchDirForSubdir('/git', 'repo7'); // expected to return /git/tools/project/repo7
```

The function I have at the moment (below) returns `undefined`, even though the `console.log` call spits out the correct path. I know I'm messing up the recursion, but can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

```
function searchDirForSubdir (dirToSearch, needle, depth = 0) {
    const DEPTH_LIMIT = 4;
    const fs = require('fs');
    for (let entry of fs.readdirSync(dirToSearch)) {
        if (depth + 1 <= DEPTH_LIMIT) {
            let fullPath = `${dirToSearch}/${entry}`;
            if (!entry.startsWith('.')
                && fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()
            ) {
                if (entry == needle) {
                    console.log(fullPath);
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    searchDirForSubdir (fullPath, needle, depth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm late to see this but i think you can gain a lot from reading my post :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a `return` clause before the line `searchDirForSubdir (fullPath, needle, depth + 1);`, if it returned something.

Your code fixed:

```
function searchDirForSubdir(dirToSearch, needle, depth = 0) {
    const DEPTH_LIMIT = 4;
    const fs = require('fs');
    for (let entry of fs.readdirSync(dirToSearch)) {
        if (depth + 1 <= DEPTH_LIMIT) {
            let fullPath = `${dirToSearch}/${entry}`;
            if (!entry.startsWith('.')
                 && fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
                if (entry == needle) {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    const found = searchDirForSubdir(fullPath, needle, depth + 1);
                    if (found)
                        return found;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the if found statement! I'd tried returning in that else but it broke the loop too soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**fs/promises and fs.Dirent**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. Here's an efficient `dirs` program using Node's fast [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects and `fs/promises` module. This approach allows you to skip wasteful `fs.exist` or `fs.stat` calls on every path -

```js
import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

async function* dirs (path = ".")
{ yield path
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield* dirs(join(path, dirent.name))
}

async function* empty () {}

async function toArray (iter = empty())
{ let r = []
  for await (const x of iter)
    r.push(x)
  return r
}

toArray(dirs(".")).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Let's get some files so we can see `dirs` working -

```sh
$ yarn add immutable     # (just some example package)
$ node main.js
```

```
[
  '.',
  'node_modules',
  'node_modules/immutable',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor',
  'node_modules/immutable/contrib/cursor/__tests__',
  'node_modules/immutable/dist'
]
```

---

**async generators**

And because we're using [async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of), we can intuitively stop iteration as soon as a matching file is found -

```js
import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join, basename } from "path"

async function* dirs // ...

async function* empty // ...

async function toArray // ...

async function search (iter = empty(), test = _ => false)
{ for await (const p of iter)
    if (test(p))
      return p   // <-- iteration stops here
}

search(dirs("."), path => basename(path) === "contrib") // <-- search for contrib
  .then(console.log, console.error)

search(dirs("."), path => basename(path) === "foobar") // <-- search for foobar
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```sh
$ node main.js
node_modules/immutable/contrib      # ("contrib" found)
undefined                           # ("foobar" not found)
```

---

**invent your own convenience**

Above `search` is a higher-order function like `Array.prototype.find`. We could write `searchByName` which probably more comfortable to use -

```js
import // ...

async function* dirs // ...

async function* empty // ...

async function toArray // ...

async function search // ...

async function searchByName (iter = empty(), query = "")
{ return search(iter, p => basename(p) === query) }

searchByName(dirs("."), "contrib")
  .then(console.log, console.error)

searchByName(dirs("."), "foobar")
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

Output is the same -

```sh
$ node main.js
node_modules/immutable/contrib      # ("contrib" found)
undefined                           # ("foobar" not found)
```

---

**make it a module**

A practice that isn't emphasised enough. By [making a module](https://javascript.info/import-export), we create a place to separate concerns and keep complexity from overwhelming the rest of our program -

```js
// FsExtensions.js

import { readdir } from "fs/promises"  // <-- import only what you need
import { join, basename } from "path"

async function* dirs // ...

async function* empty // ...

async function search // ...

async function searchByName // ...

async function toArray // ...

// ...

export { dirs, search, searchByName, toArray } // <-- you control what to export
```

```js
// Main.js

import { dirs, searchByName } from './FsExtensions' // <-- import only what's used

searchByName(dirs("."), "contrib")
  .then(console.log, console.error)

searchByName(dirs("."), "foobar")
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

---

**limiting depth**

`dirs` is implemented using a recursive generator. We can easily restrict the depth of recursion by adding a parameter to our function. I'm using a default value of `Infinity` but you can choose whatever you like -

```js
async function* dirs (path = ".", depth = Infinity)
{ if (depth < 1) return // stop if depth limit is reached
  yield path
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield* dirs(join(path, dirent.name), depth - 1)
}
```

When `dirs` is called with a second argument, the depth of recursion is limited -

```js
toArray(dirs(".", 1)).then(console.log, console.error)
// [ '.' ]

toArray(dirs(".", 2)).then(console.log, console.error)
// [ '.', 'node_modules' ]

toArray(dirs(".", 3)).then(console.log, console.error)
// [ '.', 'node_modules', 'node_modules/immutable' ]

toArray(dirs(".", 4)).then(console.log, console.error)
// [ '.',
//   'node_modules',
//   'node_modules/immutable',
//   'node_modules/immutable/contrib',
//   'node_modules/immutable/dist'
// ]
```

```js
searchByName(dirs(".", 1), "contrib").then(console.log, console.error)
// undefined

searchByName(dirs(".", 2), "contrib").then(console.log, console.error)
// undefined

searchByName(dirs(".", 3), "contrib").then(console.log, console.error)
// undefined

searchByName(dirs(".", 4), "contrib").then(console.log, console.error)
// node_modules/immutable/contrib

searchByName(dirs("."), "contrib").then(console.log, console.error)
// node_modules/immutable/contrib

searchByName(dirs("."), "foobar").then(console.log, console.error)
// undefined
```