# Create object tree from file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, recursion, filesystems

I need to get the path of the directory from the CL argument and and create an object tree, which contains the file structure of the selected directory.

If it's a file, it's value should be true. And if it's a directory I should do the same for that directory (I think the best approach is recursion).

The output should look like something like this:

```
{
  file.txt: true,
  directory: {
    one.txt: true,
    two.txt: true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

So far I tried the recursion version of that but it fails and don't know why. I think it's because I didn't handle the async part of my code properly. Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const basePath = process.argv[2]; //Getting the path (it works)
const result = {};

//Function to check my path is exist and it's a directory
const isDirectory = path => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.lstat(path, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) reject("No such file or Directory");
      resolve(stats.isDirectory());
    });
  });
};

//Recursive function that should create the object tree of the file system
const createTree = (path, target) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("Promise Oops...");
    fs.readdir(path, (err, data) => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        const currentLocation = `${path}/${item}`;
        isDirectory(currentLocation)
          .then(isDir => {
            if (!isDir) {
              target[item] = true;
              return;
            }

            target[item] = {};
            resolve(createTree(currentLocation, target[item]));
          })
          .catch(err => console.log("Oops in then..."));
      });
    });
  });
};

//Consuming the createTree function
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await createTree(basePath, result);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Oops consume...");
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fs.promises` instead of callback based methods of fs which improves the readability and helps you to find the mistakes easily.
You are logging what is returned from `createTree` function which is undefined. You should log `result` object to see the result you want.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const basePath = process.argv[2]; //Getting the path (it works)
const result = {};

//Function to check my path is exist and it's a directory
const isDirectory = async (path) => {
  try {
    const stats = await fs.promises.lstat(path);
    return stats.isDirectory();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("No such file or Directory");
  }
};

//Recursive function that should create the object tree of the file system
const createTree = async (path, target) => {
  const data = await fs.promises.readdir(path);
  for (const item of data) {
    const currentLocation = `${path}/${item}`;
    const isDir = await isDirectory(currentLocation);
    if (!isDir) {
      target[item] = true;
      continue;
    }
    target[item] = {};
    await createTree(currentLocation, target[item]);
  }
};

//Consuming the createTree function
(async () => {
  try {
    await createTree(basePath, result);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works only for one directory, it's going into the first directory and exits the function.

Answer (score 2):

**fs/promises and fs.Dirent**

Here's an efficient, non-blocking program using Node's fast [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects and [fs/promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) module. This approach allows you to skip wasteful `fs.exist` or `fs.stat` calls on every path -

```js
// main.js

import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join, basename } from "path"

async function* tokenise (path = ".")
{ yield { dir: path }
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield* tokenise(join(path, dirent.name))
    else
      yield { file: join(path, dirent.name) }
  yield { endDir: path }
}

async function parse (iter = empty())
{ const r = [{}]
  for await (const e of iter)
    if (e.dir)
      r.unshift({})
    else if (e.file)
      r[0][basename(e.file)] = true
    else if (e.endDir)
      r[1][basename(e.endDir)] = r.shift()
  return r[0]
}

async function* empty () {}
```

Now `createTree` is simply a combination of `tokenise` and `parse` -

```js
const createTree = (path = ".") =>
  parse(tokenise(path))

createTree(".")
  .then(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2)))
  .catch(console.error)
```

Let's get some sample files so we can see it working -

```sh
$ yarn add immutable     # (just some example package)
$ node main.js
```

```json
{
  ".": {
    "main.js": true,
    "node_modules": {
      ".yarn-integrity": true,
      "immutable": {
        "LICENSE": true,
        "README.md": true,
        "contrib": {
          "cursor": {
            "README.md": true,
            "__tests__": {
              "Cursor.ts.skip": true
            },
            "index.d.ts": true,
            "index.js": true
          }
        },
        "dist": {
          "immutable-nonambient.d.ts": true,
          "immutable.d.ts": true,
          "immutable.es.js": true,
          "immutable.js": true,
          "immutable.js.flow": true,
          "immutable.min.js": true
        },
        "package.json": true
      }
    },
    "package.json": true,
    "yarn.lock": true
  }
}
```

I hope you enjoyed reading this post. For added explanation and other ways to use async generators, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032850/633183).