# Is this valid syntax for node/promisify async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-promisify

I accidentally typed `await(await stat(content...` and it worked. Not sure if this is valid syntax, or there is a better way to do it? I'm trying to read all the files that are directories and do not match my regex.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const content = path.resolve('.') + '/docs' + '/'
const util = require('util');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat)
const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)
const directories = 'docs/';
const exclude = new RegExp(/^(adir|\.somedir)/,'i');
let newFiles = {}

async function main(){
    const ls = await readDir(directories)
    console.log('starting....');
    let newArray = []
     for (let index = 0; index < ls.length; index++) {
               let x =  await (await stat(content + ls[index])).isDirectory()
               let file = ls[index]
               if (x && !(exclude.test(file))){newArray.push(file)}
               console.log('x is ',x);
        }   
    console.log('new filtered array: ', newArray);
}
```

Comment: If it was invalid syntax, it wouldn't work. You can await non-promises; you just get the value.

Comment: is this a script or a part of some server code? If the former, it would be easier to use `...Sync` functions and forget about promises.

Comment: @georg no it's not, thanks. I think CertainPerformance figured out a better way.

Comment: In the async case, you don't need the `stat` call. See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options, option `withFileTypes`.

Comment: @georg looking into that ```const files = await readdir(directories,{withFileTypes:true});```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ls**

My advice would be not to put all of your eggs in one basket. We can write an ultra fast `ls` function using Node's [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects and bypass the need for a slow `fs.stat` call on *each* file -

```js
// fsext.js

import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

async function* ls (path = ".")
{ yield { dir: path }
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield *ls(join(path, dirent.name))
    else
      yield { file: join(path, dirent.name) }
}

async function toArray (iter)
{ const r = []
  for await (const v of iter)
    r.push(v)
  return r
}

export { ls, toArray }
```

```js
// main.js

import { ls, toArray } from "./fsext.js"

toArray(ls("./node_modules")).then(console.log, console.error)
```

To test it out, let's add some popular `npm` packages so we have a large hierarchy to test our our program. We'll install the lot and count the number of directories and files -

```sh
$ npm install async chalk commander debug express immutable lodash moment prop-types react react-dom request webpack

$ find ./node_modules | wc -l
```

```
5453
```

Now let's run our program and `time` it -

```sh
$ time node main.js
```

```js
[
  { dir: './node_modules' },
  { dir: 'node_modules/.bin' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/acorn' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/browserslist' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/loose-envify' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/mime' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/sshpk-sign' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/sshpk-verify' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/terser' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/uuid' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.bin/webpack' },
  { file: 'node_modules/.package-lock.json' },
  { dir: 'node_modules/@types' },
  { dir: 'node_modules/@types/eslint' },
  { file: 'node_modules/@types/eslint/LICENSE' },
  { file: 'node_modules/@types/eslint/README.md' },
  { file: 'node_modules/@types/eslint/helpers.d.ts' },
  { file: 'node_modules/@types/eslint/index.d.ts' },
  { dir: 'node_modules/@types/eslint/lib' },
   ... 5433 more items
]
```

```
node main.js  0.09s user 0.02s system 116% cpu 0.099 total
```

**dirs**

If we only want directories, we can write `dirs` as a simple specialization of our generic `ls` -

```js
// fsext.js (continued)

async function* dirs (path)
{ for await (const f of ls(path))
    if (f.dir)
      yield f.dir
}
```

```sh
$ find ./node_modules -type d | wc -l
```

```
457
```

Now compare it against our program

```js
// main.js

import { dirs, toArray } from "./fsext.js"

toArray(dirs("./node_modules")).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```sh
$ time node.main.js
```

```js
[
  './node_modules',
  'node_modules/.bin',
  'node_modules/@types',
  'node_modules/@types/eslint',
  'node_modules/@types/eslint/lib',
  'node_modules/@types/eslint/lib/rules',
  'node_modules/@types/eslint/rules',
  'node_modules/@types/eslint-scope',
  'node_modules/@types/estree',
  'node_modules/@types/json-schema',
  'node_modules/@types/node',
  'node_modules/@types/node/assert',
  'node_modules/@types/node/dns',
  'node_modules/@types/node/fs',
  'node_modules/@types/node/stream',
  'node_modules/@types/node/timers',
  'node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6',
  'node_modules/@webassemblyjs',
  'node_modules/@webassemblyjs/ast',
  'node_modules/@webassemblyjs/ast/esm',
  ... 437 more items
]
```

```
node main2.js  0.09s user 0.02s system 108% cpu 0.099 total
```

**exclude**

If we want to `exclude` certain directories or files, we can write it generically as well -

```js
// fsext.js (continued)

async function* exclude (iter, test)
{ for await (const v of iter)
    if (Boolean(test(v)))
      continue
    else
      yield v
}
```

```js
// main.js

import { dirs, exclude, toArray } from "./fsext.js"

toArray(exclude(dirs("./node_modules"), v => /@/.test(v)))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```sh
$ time node main.js
```

```js
[
  './node_modules',
  'node_modules/.bin',
  'node_modules/accepts',
  'node_modules/acorn',
  'node_modules/acorn/bin',
  'node_modules/acorn/dist',
  'node_modules/ajv',
  'node_modules/ajv/dist',
  'node_modules/ajv/lib',
  'node_modules/ajv/lib/compile',
  'node_modules/ajv/lib/dot',
  'node_modules/ajv/lib/dotjs',
  'node_modules/ajv/lib/refs',
  'node_modules/ajv/scripts',
  'node_modules/ajv-keywords',
  'node_modules/ajv-keywords/keywords',
  'node_modules/ajv-keywords/keywords/dot',
  'node_modules/ajv-keywords/keywords/dotjs',
  'node_modules/ansi-styles',
  'node_modules/array-flatten',
  ... 351 more items
]
```

```
node main.js  0.09s user 0.02s system 105% cpu 0.104 total
```

**reorganize**

In our file system extensions module, `fsext`, we wrote two functions that work on *any* iterables, not just the `ls` or `dirs`. I would suggest breaking these out into their own `iter` module. This type of reorganization helps decouple concerns and maximize code reuse throughout your entire program -

```js
// iter.js

async function* empty () {}

async function* exclude (iter = empty(), test = Boolean)
{ for await (const v of iter)
    if (Boolean(test(v)))
      continue
    else
      yield v
}

async function toArray (iter = empty())
{ const r = []
  for await (const v of iter)
    r.push(v)
  return r
}

export { empty, exclude, toArray }
```

```js
// fsext.js

import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

async function* ls (path = ".")
{ yield { dir: path }
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield *ls(join(path, dirent.name))
    else
      yield { file: join(path, dirent.name) }
}

async function* dirs (path)
{ for await (const f of ls(path))
    if (f.dir)
      yield f.dir
}

async function* files (path)
{ for await (const f of ls(path))
    if (f.file)
      yield f.file
}

export { ls, dirs, files }
```

```js
// main.js

import { dirs } from "./fsext.js"
import { exclude, toArray } from "./iter.js"

const somePath = "..."
const someTest = v => ...

toArray(exclude(dirs(somePath), someTest))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

**search**

Looking for a specific file or folder? Read on in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032850/633183) to implement `search`.

Comment: Thank you thank you, I'm going to have to check that out. I did post an answer right now but does not seem as sophisticated as yours. I like the yield.

Comment: @ritchie I'm happy to help. If you have any more questions, please don't be shy :D

Comment: Is there even a function named join() ? I'm trying to get your script to work. Had to change all the Imports to ```const { stat, readdir ,join} = require('fs').promises;``` I know there is path.join() . Oh and I tested mine with 7000 files, just a fraction of a second. I'm probably never going to have 7000 files in a directory lol. I'm working on testing yours.

Comment: Ok I got it working now, that's pretty insane that you came up with that. It's not faster than mine tested with 7000 files but then again you're is recursive which mine is not. I don't require recursive for the website. In case you are wondering yours is: 079s,084,019s... while mine is 065s,040s,018s.

Comment: `join` comes from the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) module. i don't remember which version of node adds support for `import` but it's been around for awhile. to enable it, you have to add `{ "type": "module" }` to `package.json`. 7,000 files might seem like a lot, but this was only to demonstrate that `ls` is fast even when operating on large, deep file systems. i chose a recursive procedure is because file hierarchies are recursive in structure and it's easier to reason about a program that matches the shape of the data it operates upon. all the best :D

Comment: yea I'm sure it will come in handy for a sitemap or something. I made it work with this ```const {join} = require('path')```

Comment: perfect. that's exactly how to include `path.join` using `require`

Answer (score 1):

`isDirectory` returns a `boolean`, not a `Promise<boolean>` so the second `await` is superfluous, you could just write `(await stat(content + ls[index])).isDirectory()`

Comment: Yea, you're right. That's interesting how this for loop works yet many have a  hard time using loops with async even create blogs trying to figure out how to use a loop in async huh ?

Comment: Well `await` works in for loops as well as in any code, it just uses Promise chaining under the hood. You should consider @CertainPerformance answer because your output array only depends on the corresponding file of every input file path, so you could parallelize the tasks and improve performance drastically

Answer (score 0):

Since it works, the syntax is valid - but the code is confusing and probably shouldn't be used without some tweaks. The important thing to know here is that it's valid to `await` something that isn't a Promise. If the expression on the right is a Promise, the whole thing will resolve to the value of the resolved Promise; if the expression on the right is not a Promise, the whole expression will resolve to that value. That is:

```
await Promise.resolve(5)
```

is essentially the same as

```
await 5
```

but while the second *works*, it's confusing - better to only `await` things that are Promises. `fs.isDirectory` doesn't return a Promise, so it'd be a good idea to remove the `await` from it.

There's also a better approach altogether for what you're doing: use `Promise.all` instead, so that all items in the directory can be searched through at once, instead of having to wait for them one-by-one. Your current code will take a long time if there are a whole lot of items in the directory - this is not necessary.

You can also simplify the regex by using a regex literal instead of `new RegExp`.

```
const exclude = /^(?:adir|\.somedir)/i;

async function main() {
    const filenames = await readDir(directories);
    const newArray = await Promise.all(
        filenames.map(async (filename) => {
            const fileStat = await stat(content + filename);
            if (fileStat.isDirectory && !(exclude.test(file))) {
                return filename;
            }
        })
    )
    const results = newArray.filter(Boolean);
    console.log('new filtered array: ', results);
}
```

You can also consider using `fs.promises` instead, instead of using `util.promisify`.

```
const { stat, readdir } = require('fs').promises;
```

Comment: promisify does return a promise.

Comment: @ritchie `isDirectory` does not return a Promise, so there's no sense `await`ing it. Only use *one* `await`, for `stat`.

Comment: I meant to say stat .

Comment: I got  readDir is not a function, trying to fix that. Even changed it in the ```const { stat, readdir } = require('fs').promises;```

Comment: @ritchie Make sure to use consistent capitalization. The function name is `readdir`, not `readDir`

Comment: I used readdir in both I get refrence erro cannot access stat before initilization.

Comment: @ritchie Make sure to import `stat` from `.promises` before doing the rest of your code. Put it at the top, not at the bottom. You can't access variables before defining them in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I have been in the javascript world. Can you explicitly tell me what I should import after ```const { stat, readdir } = require('fs').promises;```

Comment: The import order doesn't matter, just make sure you put the rest of the code eg `async function main()` *after* all the imports, since you can't reference variables before defining them. Just do `const { stat, readdir } = require('fs').promises;` before proceeding to use `stat` and `readdir`.

Comment: I think the problem was that you named stat and stat ```                    const stat = await stat(content + filename);``` and even then the value of that is an annoymous function.

Answer (score -1):

Much credit goes to gorg and certainPerformance. This is a simple solution.

```js
const { stat, readdir } = require('fs').promises;

async function main() {
    try {
        const getFiles = await readdir(directories, { withFileTypes: true })
        let foo = getFiles.filter(x=> x.isDirectory() && ! excludeDir.test(x.name))
        .map(f=>f.name);
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
}
```